# "stopped to talk" vs. "stopped talking"

Tags: negation, prepositional-phrases, infinitive-vs-gerund

What is difference between two sentences below?

> I stopped to talk to her.
>   I stopped talking to her.

Comment: This question is better asked on our sister site dedicated to helping people learning English as a foreign language, [ELL.se]. I have voted to move it there.

Comment: @Peter: Don't you think it needs more fixing?

Comment: @Abbasi What did you have in mind? The only other change might be "between **the** two sentences" but sometimes it is useful for an answerer to see the original to understand where the OP is coming from.

Comment: *What did you have in mind?* can be considered a non-good talk, I've flagged it of course. We also needed another *the* in *what is the difference ...*.

Answer (score 2):

There is a significant difference between the two sentences.

The first sentence should be interpreted in full as:

"I stopped [some action e.g. walking] [in order] to talk to her"

The second sentence implies that you were talking to her but have now stopped.

Comment: As a footnote, context might make it clearer why you stopped talking to her, and for how long that stoppage was. For example: “We were talking about where to eat lunch when the lawn mower went by. She couldn’t hear what I was saying, so I stopped talking to her until it was past us.” Contrast that with: “I can’t believe my sister insulted my husband like that in front of the whole family. I’ve stopped talking to her.”